# How to make search input with toggling icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have search input in the middle of the banner. I would like to create search icon to the right and if I click there, the icon disappears. I tried display:absolute, but then it is not responsive.
My code:

```
<form class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="searchForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    <img src="search-icon.png" />
  </div>
</form>

#searchForm {
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
}
```

[image: Search icon example]

Comment: Have you tried using javascript/jquery to make an on-click event to change the style from display: absolute to display: none?

Comment: @Mathieu I use in CSS :focus {display: none;} property, but also your advice would probably worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `form-control-feedback` class on a glyphicon.

HTML:

```
<form class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#searchInput:focus + i {
  display:none;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/akXPwq)